# How to set google pixel watch 1 as device owner mode / KIOSK

Tags: wear-os, android-device-owner

I have requirement to make google pixel watch-1 as device owner mode. I have following questions.

1. How to set google pixel watch-1, Device owner mode / KIOSK mode?
2. Is it possible to set google pixel watch-1 without smartphone?

Thank you in advance.

https://github.com/mrugacz95/kiosk/blob/master/README.md#locktask-mode

As per the above link, I have implemented WearOS sample app by doing following steps.

- Setting kiosk policies like
- DISALLOW_SAFE_BOOT
- DISALLOW_FACTORY_RESET
- DISALLOW_ADD_USER
- DISALLOW_MOUNT_PHYSICAL_MEDIA
- DISALLOW_ADJUST_VOLUME
- enableStayOnWhilePluggedIn(), enabled stay on device while plugged in
- Disabled status bar
- registered our app as default launcher
- Disabled keygaurd or lock screens

After installing apk into wearOS device using adb commands, I tried to run following command to set device ownwer mode.

`adb shell dpm set-device-owner app-package/.presentation.MyDeviceAdminReceiver`

But I got following exeption in terminal.

```
Exception occurred while executing 'set-device-owner':
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to set the device owner because there are already some accounts on the device.
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.enforceCanSetDeviceOwnerLocked(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:9573)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.setDeviceOwner(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:8406)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.runSetDeviceOwner(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:259)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.onCommand(DevicePolicyManagerServiceShellCommand.java:89)
    at com.android.modules.utils.BasicShellCommandHandler.exec(BasicShellCommandHandler.java:97)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:38)
    at com.android.server.devicepolicy.DevicePolicyManagerService.onShellCommand(DevicePolicyManagerService.java:9913)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:1049)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:877)
    at android.app.admin.IDevicePolicyManager$Stub.onTransact(IDevicePolicyManager.java:6054)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1285)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1244)
```

I think I was doing wrong procedure to set google Pixel Watch-1 as Device owner mode.

Therefore, I am seeking some help in online and writing this query post. Thank you in advance.